# Exchange program in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write an exchange converter in javascript combined with HTML and CSS code. The problem i get here is that i could not convert a number from one currency to another, while there are two different boxes, one for entering a value and the other for returning the exchanged value. My program simply does not convert anything. I would appreciate it if u could help.
Below is my entire code:

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <title> Converter </title>
     <style type="text/css">
     div{
     width:600px;
     height:300px;
     background-color:blue;
     margin-right: 120px;
     margin-top: 40px;
     }
    #box1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    }
   #box2{
   width:200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color:red;
   }
  p{
  font-size:12pt;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   }
  nav { font-weight : bold;
  color: white;
  border : 2px solid royalblue;
  text-align: center ;
  width: 10em;
  background-color : royalblue;}
  nav ul { display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0;}
  nav ul li { border-top: 2px solid royalblue;
  background-color : white;
  width: 10em;
       color: black;}
       nav ul li:hover { background-color : powderblue;}
       a { text-decoration: none;}
       </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function convert(){
      if(document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList1")==Euro(EUR) &&                   document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList2")==Albania(LEK)){
         var eur=document.getElementById("first");
         var e=parseFloat(eur.value);
         if(!validateForm())
         return;
         var l=e*135.82;
         var lek=document.getElementById("second");
         lek.value=l;
         }
       if(document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList1")==Albania(LEK) && document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList2")==Euro(EUR)){
       var lek=document.getElementById("first");
       var l=parseFloat(lek.value);
       if(!validateForm())
       return;
       var e=l*138.92;
       var eur=document.getElementById("second");
       lek.value=l;
       }
       }
       function validateForm(){
       var f=document.getElementById("first");
       if(f.value==""){
       alert("Jepni nje vlere");
       f.focus();
       return false;
       }
      if(isNaN(f.value){
      alert("Vlera qe dhate nuk eshte numer");
      f.focus();
      return false;
      }
      return true;
      }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="box1">
      <form action="">
      <p>Type a country or a currency</p>

      <p> <label for="txtList" >
      <input type="text" id="txtList1"
      placeholder="United States Dollars (USD)" list="currencies"/>
     <datalist id="currencies">
     <option value="United States Dollars (USD)">
     <option value="Euro(EUR)">
     <option value="Albania (LEK)">
     <option value="Paunds (PAUND)">

     </datalist>
     </label></input></p>
     <nav>Browse All
     <ul>
     <li><a href = "#" >United States Dollars (USD)</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" >Euro(EUR)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Albania (LEK)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Paunds (PAUND)</a></li>

    </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Please enter an amount </p>
    <p><label>Currency:
    <input name = "name" type = "text" id="first" size = "15"
    maxlength = "10">
    </label></p></div>
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="convert()"/>
    <div id="box2">
    <p>Type a country or a currency</p>

    <p> <label for="txtList" >
    <input type="text" id="txtList2"
    placeholder="Euro (EUR)" list="currencies"/>
    <datalist id="currencies">
    <option value="United States Dollars (USD)">
    <option value="Euro(EUR)">
    <option value="Albania (LEK)">
    <option value="Paunds (PAUND)">

    </datalist>
    </label></input></p>
    <nav>Browse All
    <ul>
    <li><a href = "#" >United States Dollars (USD)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Euro(EUR)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Albania (LEK)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Paunds (PAUND)</a></li>

    </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Please enter an amount </p>
    <p><label>Currency:
    <input name = "name" type = "text" id="second" size = "15"
     maxlength = "10">

     </label></p></div></form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

The short code:

```
     function convert(){
     if(document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList1")==Euro(EUR) && document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList2")==Albania(LEK)){
     var eur=document.getElementById("first");
     var e=parseFloat(eur.value);
     if(!validateForm())
      return;
     var l=e*135.82;
     var lek=document.getElementById("second");
     lek.value=l;
         }
     if(document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList1")==Albania(LEK) && document.getElementByOptionValue("txtList2")==Euro(EUR)){
     var lek=document.getElementById("first");
     var l=parseFloat(lek.value);
     if(!validateForm())
     return;
    var e=l*138.92;
    var eur=document.getElementById("second");
    lek.value=l;
    }
    }
    function validateForm(){
    var f=document.getElementById("first");
    if(f.value==""){
    alert("Jepni nje vlere");
    f.focus();
    return false;
    }
   if(isNaN(f.value)){
   alert("Vlera qe dhate nuk eshte numer");
   f.focus();
   return false;
   }
   return true;
   }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="box1">
  <form action="">
  <p>Type a country or a currency</p>

  <p> <label for="txtList" >
  <input type="text" id="txtList1"
   placeholder="United States Dollars (USD)" list="currencies"/>
   <datalist id="currencies">
   <option value="United States Dollars (USD)">
   <option value="Euro(EUR)">
    <option value="Albania (LEK)">
   <option value="Paunds (PAUND)">

    </datalist>
     </label></input></p>
     <nav>Browse All
       <ul>
       <li><a href = "#" >United States Dollars (USD)</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" >Euro(EUR)</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" >Albania (LEK)</a></li>
       <li><a href = "#" >Paunds (PAUND)</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
<p>Please enter an amount </p>
<p><label>Currency:
<input name = "name" type = "text" id="first" size = "15"
maxlength = "10">
</label></p></div>
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="convert()"/>
<div id="box2">
<p>Type a country or a currency</p>

<p> <label for="txtList" >
<input type="text" id="txtList2"
placeholder="Euro (EUR)" list="currencies"/>
<datalist id="currencies">
<option value="United States Dollars (USD)">
<option value="Euro(EUR)">
<option value="Albania (LEK)">
<option value="Paunds (PAUND)">

</datalist>
    </label></input></p>
    <nav>Browse All
    <ul>
    <li><a href = "#" >United States Dollars (USD)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Euro(EUR)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Albania (LEK)</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#" >Paunds (PAUND)</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
<p>Please enter an amount </p>
 <p><label>Currency:
<input name = "name" type = "text" id="second" size = "15"
maxlength = "10">

</label></p></div></form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: There’s a syntax error at `if(isNaN(f.value){`. [Use your console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525). [Use JSHint](http://jshint.com/).

Comment: i fixed this error but the same problem exists

Comment: Please boil this down to 20-30 lines of code.

Comment: ok. i will write the short code below the message

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved. For future reference, the reason why (IMO) you have been receiving downvotes is that your question shows no presentation effort: you just copied your entire code without creating a [mcve] or explaining the key functionality. Nowadays, people here expect this to be done (where applicable) and usually, it also helps you discover the problem yourself. Always reduce your code to the absolute bare minimum that is required to present the problem -- 98% chance that you will find that it's just a little mistake. Asking for help should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the logic what you intend to write. But now it will work for 2 set of values.  In the first dropdown select Euro and put some number in the text box. Similarly, select 'Albania' in the second dropdown and presse the '=' button. Now the 2nd textbox will have the converted value.

This will get to started. :)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Converter </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            width: 600px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: blue;
            margin-right: 120px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }

        #box1 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #box2 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        }

        nav {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            border: 2px solid royalblue;
            text-align: center;
            width: 10em;
            background-color: royalblue;
        }

            nav ul {
                display: none;
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

                nav ul li {
                    border-top: 2px solid royalblue;
                    background-color: white;
                    width: 10em;
                    color: black;
                }

                    nav ul li:hover {
                        background-color: powderblue;
                    }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function convert() {
            if (document.getElementById('txtList1').value == 'Euro(EUR)' && document.getElementById("txtList2").value == 'Albania (LEK)') {
                var eur = document.getElementById("first");
                var e = parseFloat(eur.value);
                if (!validateForm())
                    return;
                var l = e * 135.82;
                var lek = document.getElementById("second");
                lek.value = l;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("txtList1").value == 'Albania (LEK)' && document.getElementById("txtList2").value == 'Euro(EUR)') {
                var lek = document.getElementById("first");
                var l = parseFloat(lek.value);
                if (!validateForm())
                    return;
                var e = l * 138.92;
                var eur = document.getElementById("second");
                eur.value = e;
            }
        }
        function validateForm() {
            var f = document.getElementById("first");
            if (f.value == "") {
                alert("Jepni nje vlere");
                f.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (isNaN(f.value)) {
                alert("Vlera qe dhate nuk eshte numer");
                f.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box1">
        <form action="">
            <p>Type a country or a currency</p>

            <p>
                <label for="txtList">
                    <input type="text" id="txtList1"
                        placeholder="United States Dollars (USD)" list="currencies" />
                    <datalist id="currencies">
                        <option value="United States Dollars (USD)">
                        <option value="Euro(EUR)">
                        <option value="Albania (LEK)">
                        <option value="Paunds (PAUND)">
                    </datalist>
                </label>

            </p>
            <nav>
                Browse All
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">United States Dollars (USD)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Euro(EUR)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Albania (LEK)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Paunds (PAUND)</a></li>

            </ul>
            </nav>
            <p>Please enter an amount </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    Currency:
                <input name="name" type="text" id="first" size="15"
                    maxlength="10">
                </label>
            </p>

            <input type="button" value="=" onclick="convert()" />
            <div id="box2">
                <p>Type a country or a currency</p>

                <p>
                    <label for="txtList">
                        <input type="text" id="txtList2"
                            placeholder="Euro (EUR)" list="currencies" />
                        <datalist id="Datalist1">
                            <option value="United States Dollars (USD)">
                            <option value="Euro(EUR)">
                            <option value="Albania (LEK)">
                            <option value="Paunds (PAUND)">
                        </datalist>
                    </label>

                </p>
                <nav>
                    Browse All
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">United States Dollars (USD)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Euro(EUR)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Albania (LEK)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Paunds (PAUND)</a></li>

                </ul>
                </nav>
                <p>Please enter an amount </p>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        Currency:
                    <input name="name" type="text" id="second" size="15"
                        maxlength="10">
                    </label>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```